# The type initializer for 'Quartz.Impl.StdSchedulerFactory' threw an exception in Quartz.net

Tags: c#, quartz.net

I am using the Quartz.net for the scheduling. As soon as I run the code, it is throwing the folliwing exception in the below line.

```
ISchedulerFactory obSchedulerFactory = new StdSchedulerFactory();
```

Exception is :

```
The type initializer for 'Quartz.Impl.StdSchedulerFactory' threw an exception
```

I am not able to understand the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You most likely do not reference all required assemblies e.g. *Common.Logging.dll*.

Or `StdSchedulerFactory`s constructor fails because your app.config or web.config does not contain a section for common\logging. Does your .config file contains the following section:

```
<configSections>
  <sectionGroup name="common">
    <section name="logging" type="Common.Logging.ConfigurationSectionHandler, Common.Logging" />
  </sectionGroup>
</configSections>
<common>
  <logging>
    <factoryAdapter type="Common.Logging.Simple.TraceLoggerFactoryAdapter, Common.Logging">
      <arg key="level" value="DEBUG" />
      <arg key="showLogName" value="true" />
      <arg key="showDataTime" value="true" />
      <arg key="dateTimeFormat" value="yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss:fff" />
    </factoryAdapter>
  </logging>
</common>
```

Answer (score 0):

The error might be related to your app.config file. Try removing all the empty lines.